# CJM and its branching

Tags: customer

Do I need to build a different Customer Journey Map for each option, or can I combine them somehow?
Example: Let's say we need to make an appointment with the doctor. We can start choosing the date and time of the appointment by choosing the date, we can choose the specialization of the doctor or by entering his last name.
What is the best way to visualize this branching?